# Use FormData after passing it to a new function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm not sure if this question is worth asking but I can't seem to find a workaround so here I am.

I have a Flask app in which I submit a form that uploads an image to the server. I send the image using FormData that is created this way:

```
$( "#myform" ).submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this),
    formObject = $('form')[0],
    formData = new FormData(formObject);
    // other stuff
```

The FormData is then sent via an AJAX POST request to the sever. This operation works perfectly when the POST request is inside the submit function.

The problem is that in an other view, I need to use the same code but I moved the AJAX POST requests out of the submit function. So when I pass either my `formObject` or `formData` to the function that contains the AJAX requests, let's call it `fctA`, they are undefined.

I think I see the problem, since the submit function has a "particular status" (as you can use `$(this)` to get the form) but I can't find a way to pass the `formData` to an other function. I don't want to get rid of `fctA` since it saves me from duplicating a lot of code (because of client-side verifications)

Is there a way to pass FormData through different function calls?

Thanks in advance.

```
//Edit: Here's the code where I want to pass the FormData
//(I'm having trouble indenting it here)
    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
        //Create a JSON object to send other form inputs

        /*
        fctA is used to avoid duplicating AJAX POST requests since I
        need to send the data only when meeting some expectations and
        I must display error messages otherwise.
        */
        fctA(json, formObject)
        /*
        The image is correctly sent if I have a POST request that
        uses formData right here instead of passing it to fctA.
        As soon as the POST request leaves the submit function to go to fctA though,
        formData is undefined when I execute the code.
        I tried passing formObject or formData, they are both undefined.
        */
    },
    error: function() {
        //Display an error message
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't see a problem passing formData. Can you please post the related code?

Comment: @mm759 I have updated the question with the ajax call in which I use formData.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why exactly it does not work, but it is probably caused by your [variable scopes](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). `formObject` and `formData` are global variables because you don't declare them with `var`. `fctA` is called by the ajax-success-handler in case of a successful ajax-request. `formObject` is passed to `fctA`. Where does `formObject` come from? One might expect that it is available in the global scope. This seems not to be true for some reason.

I recommend to declare variables locally using `var` and I guess most people will agree. Global variables allow influences between arbitrary pieces of code that are hard to overlook, hard to govern and in effect hard to maintain. Global variables also increase the risk of accidently giving two variables the same name that are meant be distinct variables.

If you declare your variables locally then you can wrap your call to $.ajax in a function with `formObject` as parameter and call this function in the submit-handler. `formObject` will also be available in the ajax-success-handler because Javascript supports closures. So, if you use variable scopes the recommended way there is a good chance that you won't have the problem any more.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, I even if the problem might come from variable scopes, I don't think it is linked with the declaration of `formObject` because it is declared with `var`, look at the comma after the third line and the semicolon after `formData` is declared. So the ajax call is already wrapped in a function with `formObject` as parameter and that is `fctA`. Although, when I put the ajax call outside `fctA`, the image is correctly uploaded. Problem might be because formData is a bit weird (for example you can't see its content with console.log)

Comment: Ah, I missed the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found the solution, the problem was that I passed my formData to a function which had a keyword argument as last parameter so the formData was the value of the keyword argument (since the default value was used in that call) and of course, the argument where I expected my formData to be was undefined.

Should I delete the whole question since it's almost no more than a typo problem? The warning that tells you your account may be blocked if you delete too many questions kinds of puts me off.